How can I count and group by values in a groupArray cell in clickhouse
I have the following code:
drop table if exists statusCodes;

create table statusCodes (statusCode UInt16) engine=Memory;

insert into statusCodes values (0);
insert into statusCodes values (200);
insert into statusCodes values (200);
insert into statusCodes values (200);
insert into statusCodes values (200);
insert into statusCodes values (200);
insert into statusCodes values (201);
insert into statusCodes values (301);
insert into statusCodes values (301);
insert into statusCodes values (301);
insert into statusCodes values (301);
insert into statusCodes values (304);
insert into statusCodes values (404);
insert into statusCodes values (500);

select
    multiIf(statusCode >= 500, '5xx', statusCode >= 400, '4xx', statusCode >= 300, '3xx', statusCode >= 200, '2xx', 'errored'),
    groupArray(statusCode),
    count(1) as count
from statusCodes
group by 1;

fiddle here: https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/b3b3dfb9-1826-47a8-b201-831498c941f2
It gives me



1
2
3




4xx
[404]
1


3xx
[301, 301, 301, 301, 304]
5


2xx
[200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 201]
6


5xx
[500]
1


errored
[0]
1



But I want to have something like



1
2
3




2xx
(200, 5), (201, 1)
6


3xx
(301, 3), (304, 1)
5


4xx
(404, 1)
1


5xx
(500, 1)
1


errored
(0, 1)
1



So, to summarize, I want to group all status code by main category (2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx) and in row, another grouping by real status code of this category.

Here is a way to do it using two aggregations, the first by error group and error code, and the second by error only :
with cte as (
  select
    multiIf(statusCode >= 500, '5xx', statusCode >= 400, '4xx', statusCode >= 300, '3xx', statusCode >= 200, '2xx', 'errored') as error,
    statusCode,
    count(2) as cnt
  from status_code
  group by 1, 2
)
select error, groupArray(tuple(statusCode, cnt)) as arr, sum(cnt) as total_count
from cte
group by error
order by 1;

Results :
2xx     [(200,5),(201,1)]   6
3xx     [(301,4),(304,1)]   5
4xx     [(404,1)]           1
5xx     [(500,1)]           1
errored [(0,1)]             1

Demo here
